# What are the meanings of the codes depicts in the square brackets? For example: [MDØ68]

Tags: aeronautical-charts, approach, ils, waypoint, precision-approach

I always see these codes inside of the square brackets with different charts. Especially I wonder about the meaning of Ø.[image]

Comment: It’s just a slashed zero.

Comment: Thanx, but what about the whole meaning?

Comment: @pilot162 It’s the fix name.

Comment: Does Fix mean "A point" here? Could you be a little more descriptive? Sorry for my ignorance..

Comment: It's a point in space depicting a specific location, such as FD068 is 6 DME (nautical miles) from the VOR.  At that point (fix) you could be as low as 4200 feet on the approach.

Comment: And as for why we need a slashed zero, is to avoid confusion with the letter O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [INTRODUCTION TO
JEPPESEN
NAVIGATION CHARTS](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf) on page 78
[image]

14 Jeppesen-derived database identifiers are depicted when different from State-supplied name.